# Plot a function with respect to two parameters that are not explicitly function parameters

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d

$$function = |\delta|\frac{I_1(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)}$$
where $I_0(\kappa)$ and $I_1(\kappa)$ are the modified bessel functions of the first kind of order $0$ and $1$

I want to plot the function in a 3D space with respect to $|\delta|$ and $\tau$ where $\tau$ has the following relation with $\kappa$
$$\tau = I_0(\kappa)e^{-\kappa}$$
and $0\le|\delta|\le1$ and $0\le\tau\le1$
The result should seem like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of that exponential in the definition of `τ`, the sampling of the function is tricky, and so trying to use `ParametricPlot3D` with enough `PlotPoints`, as we would have to, kills the kernel on my machine. So let's take an indirect approach by first plotting the function for `δ = 1`. For this, we use `ParametricPlot`:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{E^-k BesselI[0, k], BesselI[1, k]/BesselI[0, k]}
  , {k, 0, 1000}
  , PlotPoints -> 200
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}]
```

resulting in

[image]

As far as I'm concerned, this is really all that matters, since `δ` is just a scale factor. But since you want the full 3D plot, here's how I back-doored the solution. We first extract the points making up the line in the plot via

```
pts = First@Cases[Normal@p1, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
```

and then construct a function from these points that interpolates the curve, and at the same time scales by `δ`:

```
f[d_, t_] := d Interpolation[pts][t]
```

Finally, then

```
Plot3D[f[d, t], {d, 0, 1}, {t, 0.013, 1}, ViewPoint -> {2.5, 1.5, 1.5}]
```

renders the following plot very fast:

[image]

Note that we have to start `t` at 0.013 because in the original plot, we took `k` out to `1000`, and

```
E^-k BesselI[0, k] /. k -> 1000.
(* 0.01261724045589 *)
```

In order to get close to `0`, you have to get `k` out farther, and this requires you to increase the `PlotPoints` by a lot (although I'm sure there's a way to tell `ParametricPlot` to sample more near `k = 0`).

---

#### Reasons

Here is a brief explanation of why I chose this back-door method. The most obvious solution is to use `ParametricPot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{d, E^-k BesselI[0, k], d BesselI[1, k]/BesselI[0, k]}
 , {k, 0, 1000}
 , {d, 0, 1}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}]
```

However, even if we increase `PlotPoints` to `100`, it still doesn't get the `tau -> 1` (`k -> 0`) behavior very well, due to the sampling and the exponential in the definition of `tau`:

[image]

Increasing `PlotPoints` further regularly crashes the kernel on my machine, so I went the indirect route. There is probably some `Option` to tell `ParametricPlot3D` how to sample the space correctly, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Note that $\tau(0)=1$ and $\lim_{\kappa\to\infty}\tau(\kappa)=0$

Comment: @sepideh. Yes that is correct. That's part of why the sampling in the plot is difficult.